# Dificuldade em agrupamento e cláusula where, no MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Preciso buscar no banco de dados os últimos 4 registros mais recentes, sendo que a coluna `exr_exa_id` esteja de acordo com os id's informados, e os `exr_exa_id` não podem ser duplicados.

Tentei agrupar de algumas maneiras, porém não tive sucesso, pois, ou não exibe os registros mais recentes, ou exibe registros iguais na coluna `exr_exa_id` (vide imagem).

Podem me ajudar?

```
SELECT * 
FROM exa_exameresultado 
WHERE 
   exr_exa_id IN (18,19,20,71) AND 
   exr_pac_id = 2128 
ORDER BY 
   exr_data DESC, 
   exr_exa_id ASC 
LIMIT 4
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca no http://sqlfiddle.com/, para você nos ajudar a te ajudar :)

Comment: segue link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58d88/1/0

Comment: Ao colocar o group by, ele altera a data...Ex: a data + recente para o campo exr_exa_id de valor 18 é 2015-04-09. Ao colocar um group by no exr_exa_id, ele altera a data deste registro para 2014-10-07

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  exa_exameresultado 
WHERE 
  exr_exa_id IN (18,19,20,71) 
AND 
  exr_pac_id = 2128 
GROUP BY 
  exr_exa_id
ORDER BY 
   exr_data DESC, exr_exa_id ASC 
LIMIT 4
```

A única mudança que fiz foi colocar um `GROUP BY exr_exa_id`.
Mas o `GROUP BY` funciona nesse caso porquê os outros campos são iguais nos seus valores também. Se depois os valores delas mudarem, talvez esse `SELECT` não sirva mais para você.